# Wildcards and dynamically generated elements

Tags: jquery

I'm using these lines to associate events to a dynamic generated element which `id` is `bill_servicesPerformed_0_quantity`.

```
$(document).on('change key paste', '#bill_servicesPerformed_0_quantity', function() {
  alert("jfls");
});
```

I works perfect but now I would like to associate the event to all the elements which `id` start with `bill_servicesPerformed` and finish with `quantity`. Is that possible? How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the starts with and ends with selectors:

`[id^="bill_servicesPerformed"][id$="quantity"]`

**[attribute selectors](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/)**